# About the relation between Schrodinger equation and temperature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, temperature, schroedinger-equation

Here is a question about temperature in quantum mechanics. I have already made [some questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature+schroedinger-equation) about this issue. Some here argue that Schrodinger equation has nothing to do with temperature, which seems logic to me. But today I found this sentence in a Quantum Mechanics semiempirical program called MOPAC:

> Ab initio MO methods provide total energies, Eeq, as the sum of
>   electronic and nuclear-nuclear repulsion energies for molecules,
>   isolated in vacuum, without vibration at 0 K.

And then

> It should be noted that M.O. parameters for MNDO, AM1, etc., are
>   optimized so as to reproduce the experimental heat of formation (i.e.,
>   standard enthalpy of formation or the enthalpy change to form a mole
>   of compound at 25oC from its elements in their standard state) as well
>   as observed geometries (mostly at 25oC), and not to reproduce the Eeq
>   and equilibrium geometry at 0 K.
>
> In this sense, ESCF (defined as Heat of formation, ΔHf), force
>   constants, normal vibration frequencies, etc. are all related to the
>   values at 25oC, not to 0 K.

One of the authors of that program also wrote:

> In ab-initio theory, the calculated total energy is equal to the
>   energy at 0K.

Is that a relation between Schrodinger equation and $T=0K$ or I am misunderstanding those paragraphs?

I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is a statistical property of a system, and it only makes sense to talk about it when the system is comprised of many constituent parts, like the atoms in a gas or a solid.

The Schrodinger equation governs the time evolution of a quantum mechanical system, and relates it to the corresponding Hamiltonian operator.

If the system is made up of only a few particles, then the concept of temperature does not even make sense.  On the other hand, if the system is made of up many particles and we are only concerned with its large-scale statistical behavior, then we might consider a simplified model where the system temperature enters as a parameter.

(By "simplified", I mean a model in which we don't consider the behavior of each individual particle, but rather the statistical average behavior over a sufficiently large number of particles)